# Optimization - Limits and simple constraint

Tags: r, optimization

I have a rather simple optimization question and while I'm fairly decent with R, optimization is something I haven't done a lot.

```
my.function <- function(parameters){
  x <- parameters[1]
  y <- parameters[2]
  z <- parameters[3]
  ((10*x^2) - ((y/2) * (z/4)))^2
}

result <- optim(c(7,10,18),fn = my.function, method = 'L-BFGS-B',
      lower = c(2,7,7),
      upper = c(15,20,20))

result$par
#[1]  2.205169 19.546621 19.902243
```

This is a made up version of the problem I'm working on, so please forgive it if its purpose makes no sense.  I have limits in place using the 'L-BFGS-B' method but I need to add a constraint and I'm unsure how to do it.  My rules that I'm trying to implement are as follows:

- x must be between 2 and 15
- y must be between 7 and 20
- z must be between 7 and 20
- **z <= y**

It's the last one I don't know how to implement.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: `L-BFGS-B` is for bound constrained problems only. `x<=y` is a real constraint so you need a different optimizer (e.g. cobyla,slsqp)

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen Thanks, I thought that might be the case.

Comment: @Balter if you want to use a native r optimization `constrOptim` will work for your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a large number to the objective function if the constraint is violated, i.e. change the last line of `my.function` to:

```
((10*x^2) - ((y/2) * (z/4)))^2 + ifelse(y > z, 10^5, 0)
```

The result in this case is the following which does satisfy the constraint. Also, since the objective is non-negative its value cannot be less than 0 so we have achieved the minimum to numeric tolerance.

```
result$par
## [1]  2.223537 19.776462 20.000000

result$value
## [1] 1.256682e-11
```

Comment: The standard counter argument for this approach, is that this is not-differentiable so it does not obey assumptions of most solvers..

Comment: We'll disagree on that.